# Write a script to connect to WPA2 network if you know name/password

Tags: networking, wireless, scripts

I would like to write a script (.sh or similar) that automatically connects to a wifi network when I know the name and password of the network.  Can anyone give me an example of how to do this?  I am having trouble getting wpa supplicant to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script to write AP config to `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` and starting up `wpa_supplicant` with the created configuration file manually. Please refer to the following example:

```
wlan_interface="wlan0" # Modify as needed
connect_wpa2_ap() {
    echo Connecting to WPA2 AP with SSID $1
    # config_wpa_supplicant $1 $2
    echo -e "\
ctrl_interface=/tmp/ctrl-$wlan_interface.pid
eapol_version=1
ap_scan=1
p2p_disabled=1
network={
ssid=\"$1\"
 scan_ssid=1
 proto=RSN
 key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
 pairwise=CCMP TKIP
 group=CCMP TKIP
 psk=\"$2\"
}
" >/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
    /sbin/wpa_supplicant -i "$wlan_interface" -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
}
```

Connect with `connect_wpa2_ap <ssid> <password>`.